# Nested custom collection class | Runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following custom class LinkEnd, where Portal is another custom class I created:

```
Option Explicit
Private ePortal As Portal
Private eHeading As Double
Public Property Get Portal() As Portal
    Portal = ePortal
End Property
Public Property Let Portal(Value As Portal)
    ePortal = Value
End Property
Public Property Get Heading() As Double
    Heading = eHeading
End Property
Public Property Let Heading(Value As Double)
    eHeading = Value
End Property
```

I am using the LinkEnds in the class Link:

```
Option Explicit
Private LinkEnds As New Collection
Public Sub Add(p As Portal)
    Dim NewLinkEnd As New LinkEnd

    With NewLinkEnd
        .Portal = p
    End With

    LinkEnds.Add NewLinkEnd
End Sub
```

I checked; the NewLinkEnd is defined fine; the problem is with the line

```
.Portal = p
```

How do I correctly assign the Portal inside the NewLinkEnd? I used almost identical code for a Custom Collection Class Portals which is a Collection of Portal objects, and it works fine there...

Comment: can you post your whole LinkEnds class?  How is your Portal property created in that class?

Comment: shouldn't it be Property Set, not Property Let ? And then Set .portal = p

Comment: At first glance I see:  **`Portal = ePortal`** and **`ePortal As Portal`**.  Looks kinda _circular_ to me;  Here's some [information on classes from the amazing Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx).

Comment: Portal = ePortal where ePortal is defined as an instance of the portal class is perfectly fine - and not at all circular. You need to distinguish the portal property of the linkend class from the private variable eportal which stores the value of that property. The problem is that ePortal is an object and must be Set

Comment: @sous2817 Portal isn't a Property of the LinkEnds class, but of the LinkEnd class. LinkEnds is a collection of type LinkEnd. Portal p is created elsewhere in the code; that part works fine. I just need to get p into NewLinkEnd.Portal

Comment: if you step through the code, you'll see that the error is really when trying to add to the .Portal property and not really at the ".Portal = p" line.  You should post the LinkEnd class as that's where the problem lies.

Comment: @sous2817 the full LinkEnd class is already posted at the top of my original post. You are right, stepping through the code the error is at the end of the Get Portal() property. I've tried Harassed Dad's suggestion, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I just rewrote the whole thing and made Heading a property of the Portal. Now Links are just a collection of Portals; problem solved.